# How would I select multiple summed columns each with their own condition in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Basically:

1. I have a number representing an amount of time in minutes, we'll call my_minutes
2. I have an aircraft type that any record within the table must first match on to be qualified (WHERE)
3. There are 12 months worth of Minutes data for each month, in the form of month_01_minutes, month_02_minutes, month_03_minutes...
4. If a particular field for that month is within +/- 10% of the provided number of minutes, add that to the sum
5. If the value isn't less than/greater than 10% of my provided amount of minutes (my_minutes), return 0 for that select column in particular
6. At the end, I'd like to sum up each of the selected values for a grand total of everything

select 
   sum( if(month_01_minutes <= 0.9 * my_minutes and month_01_minutes >= 1.1 * my_minutes, month_01_minutes, 0 ) ),

sum( if(month_02_minutes <= 0.9 * my_minutes and month_02_minutes >= 1.1 * my_minutes, month_02_minutes, 0 ) ),
where tableName.aircraft_type = providedAircraftType

[Table with all of the minute data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHPWj.png)

I've tried it with just one column, but the "where" clause of this just returns a zero value despite there being a field with a value that is within +/- 10% of 225

```
select
    sum(case when c.month_01_minutes <= 0.9 * 225 and c.month_01_minutes >= 1.1 * 225 then c.month_01_minutes else 0 end)

from fumes_schema.consumption c

where c.aircraft_type = 'xyz';
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and improve your question accordingly.

Comment: Reconsider this table design with suffixed columns. With a normalized structure, storage and querying are much more efficient. Wide formats should be used as final step for end use needs.

Comment: *despite there being a field with a value that is within +/- 10% of 225* ... We need to see data to help, otherwise only you can determine this. Is such a value limited to `xyz` aircraft type and `month_01_minutes` column?

Answer (score 0):

The predicate was wrong, a number could not be smaller than 90% and bigger than 110% at same time,it would always return false.

```
select
    sum(case when /* c.month_01_minutes <= 0.9 * 225 and */ c.month_01_minutes >= 1.1 * 225 then c.month_01_minutes else 0 end)
from fumes_schema.consumption c

where c.aircraft_type = 'xyz';
```